# MySQL++ Application error at launch

Tags: mysql, dll, mysql++

I compiled MySQL++ with no issues. When I launched some of the executables (resetdb.exe and simple1.exe) they suggest to run to test if the installation has been successful, the first error I got was that `libmysql.dll` was missing.

Adding its path to the PATH environment variable did not fix the problem, even after launching a new command prompt; I had to copy the DLL in the directory where MySQL++ executables are.

Now the DLL is found, but I get this error:

```
simple1.exe - Application error
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). 
Click OK to close the application.
```

even launching from the command line, I get no more information than these.

Thank you for any help!

MySQL 5.5 -
MySQL++ 3.0.9 -
Windows 7 64 bits -
MINGW32 -
GCC 4.4.0

Answer (score 1):

0xC000007B is a Windows error that means the executable is corrupted. It could refer either to `simple1.exe` or to one of the DLLs it's linking against.

Some reasons this could happen:

- You're mixing toolchains in an incompatible way. In your case, you may have built `simple1.exe` using pieces built by MinGW GCC and pieces built by Visual C++. MinGW *should* be compatible with any pure C DLL built by Visual C++, including the MySQL C API DLL. However, you may have other pieces interfering. MinGW *isn't* compatible with VC++ at the C++ level, but then, it shouldn't have linked at all if this were your problem.
- You didn't follow the MySQL C API import library build steps in `README-MinGW.txt`. You either missed a step, or skipped it entirely and are trying to use the import library that shipped with MySQL.
- In your previous gyrations, you ended up with a corrupt object file, which got linked in. Try saying `make clean all` at the top level of MySQL++ to force a complete rebuild.
- You're mixing versions of MySQL or MySQL++. If you have more than one version of each on the system, make sure you're consistent in their use. That is, build the C API import library from the same DLL you run the programs against, use `exrun.bat` to run the examples to ensure you're using the just-built version of the MySQL++ DLL instead of another you have in your PATH, etc.

Additionally, I note that you're using an older version of MySQL++. If you were on Linux, I could understand that as some distributions still ship with 3.0.9. But since you have to build MySQL++ from source with MinGW, I don't see why you're not using 3.1.0. Did you get a binary build from somewhere?

As for your `PATH` problem, did you restart the MinGW shell after doing this? PATH updates don't affect running programs; they keep the value they saw when they started.